# how to get to the most inner XML of a recursive node in beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

using this code

```xml
<BrowseNodes>
    <BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNodeId>3404981</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>Tires</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNodeId>6388965011</BrowseNodeId>
                <Name>Tires & Tubes</Name>
                <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>3403201</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>Cycling</Name>
                        <Ancestors>
                            <BrowseNode>
                                <BrowseNodeId>3375301</BrowseNodeId>
                                <Name>Categories</Name>
                                <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                                <Ancestors>
                                    <BrowseNode>
                                        <BrowseNodeId>3375251</BrowseNodeId>
                                        <Name>Sports & Outdoors</Name>
                                    </BrowseNode>
                                </Ancestors>
                            </BrowseNode>
                        </Ancestors>
                    </BrowseNode>
                </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
        </Ancestors>
    </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
```

I am trying to use beautiful soup to get the most inner-placed node.  In this case "Sports & Outdoors".  Because I don't know how many layers a BrowseNode can go into, how do I get the most inner one if the assumption is that the most inner one is the root I need?

Thanks

Comment: What makes `Sports & Outdoors` any more innermost than `3375251`?

Comment: it doesn't....my question was about the <BrowseNode> tags....I don't know how far it'll go in.  that means to me it's recursive.  What I want is the <Name> value of the inner-most <BrowseNode> tag. Thanks.

Comment: OK, do you have to deal with the possibility that a `BrowseNode` may have two `BrowseNode` children, one of which goes deeper than the other, or can you rely on the fact that every `BrowseNode` has exactly 0 or 1 `BrowseNode`s underneath it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the fact that every `BrowseNode` either has a `BrowseNode` descendant or doesn't, this is pretty simple:

```
def deepest(root, tag):
   descendant = root.find(tag)
   if descendant:
       return deepest(descendant, tag)
   return root
```

(You can make that more concise, but I wanted to keep the logic as obvious as possible.)

If a `BrowseNode` might have 2 or more `BrowseNode` descendants, and you have to find the deepest one, then you have to modify this to do a depth-first search. Which isn't too hard; you just have to make `deepest` return `(level, node)` instead of just `node`, use `find_all` instead of `find`, and do `max(deepest(descendant, tag) for descendant in descendants)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to get the deepest-nested one anywhere in the document you can look at all of them and then count parents. Performance should be ok on a non-huge document. Note: this does not handle the case of 2 such elements with the same depth as siblings or in different places.

```python
depths = (
    (elem, sum(1 for p in elem.parents if p.name == 'BrowseNode'))
    for elem in soup.findAll('BrowseNode'))
deepest_elem, deepest_depth = max(depths, key=lambda t:t[1])
```